# Importing modules for visual studio

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Right now i'm trying to create an array like this:

```
import NumPy as np

V = np.array([3, 9, 7, 7, 7, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5])

print V
```

but the terminal is saying "Unable to import NumPy" and "Missing module docstring"

I am fairly new to coding on visual studio and I don't often use Stackoverflow either... Basically I'm not a pro at coding. I've googled for solutions but I'm still confused. Apologies for the simple question.

I know you can download python tools on a github website but I don't know how that will link to my VS. I tried finding out the version I have and I think it is Version 1.10.2 (1.10.2).

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace? Can you reinstall numpy using pip?

Answer (score 1):

First :
Make sure that numpy is already existed .try that outside VS.

```
import numpy
```

you will get ModuleNotFound error if it's not existed.

Second : Update your environment database in the Visual Studio.

Third  : make sure the the environment settings is correct .

Four : If previous steps don't work you may delete your current environment 
         and  define new one and create new project .

Answer (score 0):

It's `numpy` not `NumPy`

You want:

```
import numpy as np

V = np.array([3, 9, 7, 7, 7, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5])

print V
>>
[3 9 7 7 7 1 5 5 5 5]
```

Comment: it says the same thing!

Comment: @John Can you provide the full stack trace? Can you reinstall numpy using pip?

Comment: i have installed python version 3.6.0 which apparently includes pip, but when i type: >>> pip install -U pip it    it says invalid syntax.

Comment: I'm looking into installing numpy and Scipy packages now.. but i have no idea how that has an effect on visual studio app....

Comment: @John How did you originally install Python?

Comment: @John And which version of Visual studio are you using?

Comment: @Did you install a Python interpreter to go with your Visual Studio install?

Comment: when i download the corresponding version of numpy it asks me to open it in some random application that I don't even use for coding.. Totally lost

Comment: Visual Studio Code Version 1.11.1 (1.11.1)

Comment: On VSC there is a drop down menu of all the possible languages you want to code in.. but even when I make a python file it doesn't have the numpy package

Comment: OK, bear with, can you go to `Tools` -> `Python Tools` -> `Python Environments` -> `pip` and then click on `install numpy` if it is available?

Comment: @John, I think, when you typed in `pip install -U` you were typing it in Visual Studio, rather than in the command line?

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `NumPy` by `numpy`

Comment: it says the same thing!